# Get SSL/TLS certificate on Amazon EC2 server

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, https

I tried following [these official instructions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-an-instance.html) for getting SSL on my EC2 instance. For step two, I used the following information:

```
Country Name:   US    
State or Province Name: Indiana
Locality Name:  Indianapolis
Common Name:    mikewarren.me
Email Address:  admin@mikewarren.me
```

mikewarren.me was obtained via Google Domains, and maps straight to my EC2 public IP address. The e-mail address maps to my personal e-mail.

I am following the rest of the instructions, submitting CSR.pem to StartCom for the certificate, and installing the certs they give me. However, when I test it [through SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=mikewarren.me), it comes up not trusted, as somehow, common name is the e-mail address I entered.

I tried contacting Amazon Web Services about this, but they're too busy to try to fix this.

What should I do here, so that my server uses SSL/TLS?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing AWS would be able to help you with here, so no reason trying to open a ticket with them. If you want to open a ticket with someone it should be StartCom.

<s>I looked at the certificate on your site and it appears that either you didn't enter the value you think you did in the Common Name field, or StartCom somehow mangled the certificate they issued to you. At this point I would revoke the certificate and try going through the process of creating a new one.</s>

See @Michael-sqlbot's comment. You didn't install the correct cert on your server.

Comment: The common name in this case is an email address instead of domain.

Comment: The cert is not mangled -- it looks fine except for the minor detail that it's not a server certificate.  OP has somehow managed to install his *client* certificate -- the one StartCom issues to you for use (instead of a password) when authenticating to their web site -- on his web server. Note that the Issuer of the cert is "StartCom Class 1 **Client** CA."  So, it's not a problem with the cert... as much as it's not the correct cert.  Revocation not needed, but the right cert needs to be found and installed.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot ah it all makes sense now. You should post that as the answer and I'll delete my answer.

Comment: Amazon Web Services should have stated this in their tutorial. Question: is the server certificate also used when logging into the server?

Comment: @MikeWarren this has nothing to do with AWS or their tutorial. It is specifically the way StartSSL requires you to have a client cert to login to your StartSSL account. You have taken that client cert and installed it on your server instead of installing the actual cert generated for your server.

Comment: @MarkB could you provide personal help with this issue, via TeamViewer (or something similar)? or, could you spell out the steps?

Comment: @MikeWarren it isn't that you got the steps wrong installing the cert ... it looks as if you did the right thing, but with the wrong kind of certificate.  You are using a "Client-S/MIME" certificate from StartSSL, not a server certificate. The client cert is only used on your own computer when you authenticate yourself to their web site.